# What should be the acceptable number of watchers in my angularjs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, browser

I have an angularjs app and I feel it renders slower than an average webpage on the browser. I started thinking about the watchers on my app and found [this little script](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef#.etvp5o13z) that returned all the watchers on my page.

I do not know how big a number should be acceptable for a good user experience considering if more the watchers do always reduce the responsiveness of the page.

Comment: Just a note, you can use Batarang chrome plugin also to see many of the performance related metrics and like this and see which watcher is executing for longest time and improve on that. There is no acceptable number of watchers, you should try to keep them as low as possible.

Comment: In my experience, anything below 1000 is usually fine, in the sense that watch evaluation isn't the source of any performance problems. But it also depends on how often the watched values change, and what DOM manipulations are needed in response to those changes.

Comment: My application has ~ 800 wacthers and it seemed a bit slow. Maybe I should look at how frequently those are changed as you suggest.

Comment: This is a previously answered (in good detail), here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018821/should-i-always-bind-functions-to-scope-objects